# quotas not linked to users but to directories

Tags: directory, quota

Usually, quotas are enforced per user, as related to the proprietary of the file.

Is it possible to apply a quota on a folder basis, in such a way, that a folder contents are limited in disk space?

Comment: This can be done on btrfs and zfs with pools. It can't be done with ext4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same question asked and answered over here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148715/how-to-set-limit-on-directory-size-in-linux

basically, make a virtual filesystem by filling a file with zeros to the size you want, then create a filesystem in that file and then loopmount it to the directory you want to limit.

Linux Quartly article about it here:
  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/directory-quota-601140/

Tutorial here:
  http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/quota_tutorial.html

Comment: OK, but this reserves the space form the beginning. It really does not help to save disk space. Does this mean, that there is **NO** solution to this problem that keeps used disk space minimal ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: You can limit the use of actually used diskspace by using a sparse-file instead of a full-fledged file. Though you can easy run [into trouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file#Disadvantages) when the disk space on the *real HDD* runs out. E.g. `truncate -s 512M foo;` The filesystem (e.g. ext3) is going to make the file less sparse but the ocupied size is still much lower. E.g. a 100MiB sparse file ocupy about 7.7 MiB of space after it has been formatted with ext3.