# Find out which users are hogging the most disk space on our data server

Tags: disk-usage, sort, storage

We are supposed to store our ongoing projects on a rather small (~4TB) data server. Not surprisingly, it is constantly overflowing and people need to move off less recent files manually.
Is there an easy (aka standard command-line) way to find out which users take up the most space in a directory? i.e. summing up the size of all files in a directory and all sub-directories belonging to each user?

Edit: ideally not following symlinks

Comment: Have you considered enabling disk quotas?

Answer (score 0):

To find the disk usage by all users on the disk, you can use the following script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN=/home

readarray -t user_list<<<"$(cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 1)"

for u in "${user_list[@]}" ; do
        printf "Scanning for user: %30s" "$u"
        du -ch $(find "$DIRECTORY_TO_SCAN" -user "$u" 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null | sed -e '/total/!d;s/^/    /'
done
```

This script will scan the list of all users, find the files you can read and they own and compute the total space those files use.

---

(The part below is kept for the sake of completeness)

If you want to know the full size of a directory, you can use the `du` command:

```bsh
du -sh directory1 directory2
```

will print the size of the directory and all its contents.

To actually solve your problem, you could use [user (or group) quotas](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-disk-quotas). This would allow you to get a detailled report of how much space each user/group is taking and set hard limits about how much space they may use.

Comment: I can't actually solve the problem since I am not the admin. What usually happens is: I realise that the storage is full again and have to ask around who could free up some space. The response I usually get is: "I barely use any space on the server, so I can't". The directory tree is not branched by users, but by projects since more than one person is working on the same project.

Comment: The problem with the non-admin approach is that if the permissions on a directory are set that you cannot read it/list its contents, you cannot know what is in there and cannot find the space it uses. If it is such a problem, I think the server admin should do something (like group quotas and set one group per project or set up [directory quotas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99191/quotas-not-linked-to-users-but-to-directories)).

Comment: The solution only working for dirs that I have permission to read would be fine. I agree that it should be the responsibility of the admin... but can we for now just pretend that this is not an option and I would like an answer to the initial question.

Comment: @MechEng I updated my answer with a script that does what you want

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, I usually first use `du -kx | sort -rn | less` to list the directories in a largest-first order. That tells me where the biggest individual disk hogs are, so I'll know where to look. But as @SimonDoppler said, if you don't have at least `r-x` access to all the sub-directories, your listing will be incomplete: you'll only be able to get the sizes of directories you'll be able to access.

Remember: normally you only need to have write access to a directory to delete any files in it. Only if the directory has the `sticky` bit set (i.e. the last letter in the permission letter string is a `t` instead of `x`), you need be the owner of the file in order to delete it.

If there is no quota available, you may need to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "" ] || [ "$1" = "-h" ]
then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <directory> <username(s)...>" >&2
    exit 64 # EX_USAGE
fi
if ! [ -d "$1" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: directory $1 does not exist" >&2
    exit 66 # EX_NOINPUT
fi

REPORTROOT="$1"
shift
for U in "$@"
do
    # Find all files under $REPORTROOT owned by a particular user,
    # get their sizes and sum them together.
    DISKUSE=$(find "$REPORTROOT" -type f -user "$U" \
        -exec stat -c %s {} \+ 2>/dev/null \
        | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf("%ld\n", s)}')
    # Display the result for this user.
    printf "%16s: %d\n" "$U" "$DISKUSE"
done
```

Note that running this may take a while.

The "calculate a sum of a list of numbers" awk one-liner is from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450821/9197000). Note the comments of the answer.