# Why can't you move another user's directory when you can move their file?

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, mv

Following on from [another user's question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527148/can-a-user-be-unable-to-delete-files-within-a-directory-the-user-owns) I've bumped into a quirk of Linux filesystem permissions that I can't easily rationalize:

```bsh
sudo mkdir ~/foo ~/foo/bar
sudo touch ~/baz
mkdir ~/my_dir
chown 700 ~/my_dir
# this is fine
mv ~/baz ~/my_dir
# renaming is fine
mv ~/foo ~/bob
# Moving caused: Permission denied
mv ~/bob ~/my_dir/
```

For clarity `foo` `foo/bar` `baz` are owned by root.  `my_dir` is owned by my own user and of course `~` is owned by my own user.  I can rename and *move* a file owned by another user.  I can rename a directory owned by another user, but I can't *move* a directory owned by another user.

This seems a very specific restriction and I don't understand what danger is being protected against or what underlying mechanism means that it can only work this way.

Why can other users' directories not be moved?

Comment: I can't see how you used `~/foo` and `~/foo/bar`, or why `~/baz` is a directory. Or how `~/baz` got renamed twice, or where `~/bob` came from.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks, typo in my question, I think that's fixed now.  `baz` is a file.  it's `foo` then `bob` that is a directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one of the situations [documented](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html#ERRORS) to lead to `EACCES`:

> `oldpath` is a directory and
>                 does not allow write permission (needed to update  the
>                 `..`  entry).

You can’t write inside `bob`, which means you can’t update `bob/..` to point to its new value, `my_dir`.

Moving files doesn’t involve writing to them, but moving directories does.

Comment: I honestly never knew that `..` actually existed, I always thought it was simulated by the OS.  Now I'm trying to find if `.` actually exists.

Comment: `.` usually exists too; that’s why directories have a link count >= 2.

Comment: It's not April 1 so you must be being serious.  This win's the prize esoteric fact of the month!  I'm sure if I ask questions like "why" I'm going to get the answer "performance", or "simpler implementation".  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, on some fs (btrfs) dirs have a link count if 1. `.` and `..` are emulated by the VFS on such fs. I'm not able to test now, but I'm pretty sure that it's also emulating that EACCES condition too (which is not that esoteric).

Comment: @pizdelect indeed. I’m pretty sure there’s a question here whose answers go into all those details (why `.` and `..`, why some FSs store them while others emulate them, etc.), but I can’t find it... (IIRC the link count of 2 or more is a POSIX requirement.)

Comment: Is it? Then clearly Linux is not POSIX compliant because it will return a link count of 1 for dirs on some FSs. I know that from failing naive `find -links` usage examples.

Comment: @pizdelect right, `/proc/sys` for starters; I’m probably mis-remembering. All that I can find now is that POSIX requires that [`.` and `..` appear to exist](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13) (without defining how they’re implemented).

Comment: @pizdelect POSIX allows `.` and `..` to be emulated. See `readdir()` where it says **If entries for dot or dot-dot exist, one entry shall be returned for dot and one entry shall be returned for dot-dot; otherwise, they shall not be returned.** So they don't have to actually exist.

Comment: @Barmar and that's exactly what I was saying -- if the entries don't exist, are emulated by the kernel, just as the EACCES condition. It's the extra link which is not emulated -- "leaf" dirs have a link count of 1 in some FSs like btrfs.

Comment: @StephenKitt Can you cite where POSIX specifies that the link count has to be emulated even if the special directory entries don't really exist?

Comment: @Barmar see my follow-up comment above; I haven’t found the requirement in POSIX.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you were contradicting your earlier comment about the link count.